# Need Help Join Collection

Tags: mongodb

Collection Inventory sample data:

```
{
    "_id" : "89011704252315531324",
    "sku" : "A2015-01-000",
    "type" : "package",
    "status" : "active",
    "lng" : "-72.789153",
    "lat" : "44.173515",
    "acq" : "28",
    "gtime" : ISODate("2017-01-11T22:27:48.000Z"),
    "qlng" : "-72.796501",
    "qlat" : "44.214783",
    "qtime" : ISODate("2016-11-27T18:21:10.000Z"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-01-12T14:43:29.000Z"),
    "modified" : Date(-62135596800000),
    "battery" : "60",
    "wearables" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "0009003C100228234E45",
            "type" : "wearable",
            "status" : "active",
            "battery" : "50",
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-01-12T11:43:33.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "004A003F200B36634E45",
            "type" : "cradle",
            "status" : "active",
            "battery" : "64",
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-01-11T22:27:26.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "11223344556600000B55",
            "type" : "falldetect",
            "status" : "active",
            "battery" : "64",
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-01-12T08:43:29.000Z")
        }
    ],
    "company" : "ConnectAmericaProduction",
    "companies" : [],
    "remoteIp" : "172.31.45.196:53864",
    "subscriber" : "5783e20aa2c89f346e000006",
    "ring" : "90",
    "speaker" : "90",
    "mic" : "55",
    "version" : "4352",
    "cradle" : "OFF",
    "ctime" : ISODate("2017-01-11T23:13:59.000Z"),
    "csqtime" : Date(-62135596800000)
}
```

collection calllog sample data

```
{
    "_id" : "89011704252315531324",
    "cdr" : [ 
        {
            "direction" : "Outgoing",
            "duration" : 46,
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-11-23T03:25:06.000Z"),
            "number" : "",
            "name" : "Call Center",
            "lng" : "-71.208061",
            "lat" : "42.330265",
            "acq" : "",
            "timezone" : {
                "dstOffset" : 0.0,
                "rawOffset" : 0.0,
                "status" : "",
                "timeZoneId" : "",
                "timeZoneName" : ""
            }
        }, 
        {
            "direction" : "Incoming",
            "duration" : 51,
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-11-23T03:26:02.000Z"),
            "number" : "",
            "name" : "Call Center",
            "lng" : "-71.205727",
            "lat" : "42.333347",
            "acq" : "",
            "timezone" : {
                "dstOffset" : 0.0,
                "rawOffset" : 0.0,
                "status" : "",
                "timeZoneId" : "",
                "timeZoneName" : ""
            }
        }, 
        {
            "direction" : "Outgoing",
            "duration" : 49,
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-11-27T18:21:04.000Z"),
            "number" : "",
            "name" : "Call Center",
            "lng" : "-72.796501",
            "lat" : "44.214783",
            "acq" : "",
            "timezone" : {
                "dstOffset" : 0.0,
                "rawOffset" : -18000.0,
                "status" : "OK",
                "timeZoneId" : "America/New_York",
                "timeZoneName" : "Eastern Standard Time"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

after run this aggrgrate function

```
 db.calllog.aggregate([{$unwind: "$cdr"}, {$lookup:{from: "inventory", localField: "_id", foreignField: "_id", as: "wearables" }}, { "$project": { "cdr.direction": 1, "cdr.duration": 1,"cdr.date": 1,"wearables.type": 1, "wearables.status": 1, "wearables.battery": 1} }])
```

Result:

```
{ "_id" : "89011704252315531324", "cdr" : { "direction" : "Outgoing", "duration" : 46 }, "wearables" : [ { "type" : "package", "status" : "active", "battery" : "60" } ] }
{ "_id" : "89011704252315531324", "cdr" : { "direction" : "Incoming", "duration" : 51 }, "wearables" : [ { "type" : "package", "status" : "active", "battery" : "60" } ] }
{ "_id" : "89011704252315531324", "cdr" : { "direction" : "Outgoing", "duration" : 49 }, "wearables" : [ { "type" : "package", "status" : "active", "battery" : "60" } ] }
```

needed help can not get query to shows wearables type such as wearable, cradle, falldetect

thank

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to do `wearables.wearables.type`? When you call wearables.type, you are actually getting the type of the Inventory. If you need the type of the wearable that is inside the inventory. You need to put inventory.wearables.type. The initial problem is that you're calling the inventory "wearables" and making a confusion out of it.

I would do the following:

```
db.calllog.aggregate([{$unwind: "$cdr"},
      {$lookup:{from: "inventory", localField: "_id", foreignField: "_id", as: "inventory" }},
      {$unwind: "$inventory.wearables"},
      { "$project": {
          "cdr.direction": 1,
          "cdr.duration": 1,
          "cdr.date": 1,
          "inventory.type": 1,
          "inventory.status": 1, 
          "inventory.battery": 1,
          "inventory.wearables.type":1
      }}])
```

Comment: Did you try to remove the projections?

Comment: I got it to run in MongoDB but when i tried to passed this in R if give me a error.

Comment: m <- mongo( db = "ionmom")
m6<-m$aggregate('[{"$unwind":"$cdr"}, {$lookup:{from: "inventory", localField: "_id", foreignField: "_id", as:"inventory"}},{$unwind: "$inventory"}, {"$project":{ "$project": {"cdr.duration": 1, "inventory.wearables.type":1, "inventory.wearables.status":1, "inventory.wearables.battery":1 }}}]') 
Error: Invalid JSON object: [{"$unwind":"$cdr"}, {$lookup:{from: "inventory", localField: "_id", foreignField: "_id", as:"inventory"}},{$unwind: "$inventory"}, {"$project":{ "$project": {"cdr.duration": 1,          "inventory.wearables

Comment: Yeah, but your question was in mongodb. If my answer address your question problem. Why don't you kindly upvote/accepts it? Your R question should be in a different question (which unfortunately I don't know how to answer)